# c++/cli sintaxis: Error: 'new' or 'override' is required because this declaration matches function

Tags: inheritance, c++-cli, abstract-class

I want to write a wrapper with c++/cli to communicate  a c++ library with a C# graphic interface.

My problem appear when I want to implement the inheritance in c++/cli:
The idea:
abstract class B inherits from abstract class A
class C inherits from abstract class B

```
public ref class A_Wrapper abstract
{
public:
A_Wrapper(void);
virtual double solve(OtherWrapper ^) =0;
};       
public ref class B_Wrapper abstract: public A_Wrapper 
{ 
private:
B * nativeLS;
public:
B_Wrapper(void);
virtual double solve(OtherWrapper ^) =0;
virtual B * getNative();
};
```

The error I find is: 
Error:'new' or 'override' is required because this declaration matches function A:solve

If I use virtual `double solve(OtherWrapper ^) override;` instead of using `virtual double solve(OtherWrapper ^) =0;`  and I implement the member function in the .cpp file, then it works. I want B_Wrapper to be abstract, so that I do not have to implement `B_Wrapper::solve(..)`. what am I missing?

Hope I have been clear and someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove `solve` from your declaration of `B_Wrapper`.

Because you're inheriting from `A_Wrapper`, the `solve` method is already declared. You don't need to declare it again just to re-iterate the fact that the method has no implementation.

```
public ref class A_Wrapper abstract
{
public:
    A_Wrapper(void);
    virtual double solve(OtherWrapper ^) =0;
};

public ref class B_Wrapper abstract: public A_Wrapper 
{ 
private:
    B* nativeLS;
public:
    B_Wrapper(void);
    virtual B * getNative();
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The C++/CLI compiler is trying to stop you from shooting your foot off.  The B_Wrapper class has *two* methods named solve().  The one inherited from A_Wrapper and the one you added.  The added one *hides* the inherited one.

This scenario is a very common bug in C++, induced when modifying a virtual method by adding a parameter.  Such a method no longer overrides the base method if that one wasn't edited as well.  Pretty tricky to diagnose.  The C++/CLI language was early to do something about it.  Later adopted into C++11 with the addition of the `override` modifier.  You must use `override` if you want to override the base method and explicitly use `new` when hiding was intended.

With very high odds that neither was intended here since you don't actually override the abstract method and there's no conceivable reason why you'd want to hide the inherited one.  Just delete the solve() method declaration in B_Wrapper, you already inherited the one from A_Wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved with 'override' keyword in following way.

### Base class

```
ref class DataBackUp
{
    public:
       virtual void StartBackUp(void) = 0;
};
```

### Derived class

```
ref class FlatBackup : public DataBackUp 
{
    public:
        void StartBackUp(void) override
        {
        }

};
```